# Need to restrict disabled series/legends into export to csv file for HighChart pie chart

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts library for generating charts.
In Pie chart, while exporting data into CSV file, I want to restrict disable legends/series data into csv file.

I did below things:

```
...
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
   point: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function(e) {
                            const chart = this,
                                series = chart.series;
                            debugger;
                            console.log(series[1])
                            series[1].update({
                                type: 'pie',
                                showInLegend : false
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
  }
}
...
```

In this case I got series[1] undefined. And from other charts like (Column, Bar, Line) automatically disabled series/legends are not display in csv file.

Thanks in an advance

Answer (score 1):

Your code configuration seems to be incorrect. Try this:

```
  point: {
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(e) {
        const point = this,
          series = point.series;
        series.update({
          type: 'pie',
          showInLegend: false
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4unz90kv/

Comment: I already tried that. In that case all of the legends are gone.

Comment: Apologize for misunderstanding your issue. I noticed that you have already asked the same question at our forum, so the thread will be continued there https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=51188